# IronRuby 1.3.1 VS 2010 SP1 Installation Issue

Tags: ironruby, visual-studio-2010

I've downloaded the latest release of IronRuby from codeplex and ran the install with no issues.

However when I come to create a project i receive the message:

IronRuby installation not found. Although basic scripts should work standard libraries and gems won't be available....."

This seems to be an issue with vs2010 sp1 from the project issue tracker on codeplex, but theres no fix mentioned there. I only really wanted this release for the tools support so using 1.0 is something I want to avoid.

Has anyone got any workrounds/fixes/advice?

Answer (score 1):

I used [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) to install IronRuby.  When I did so, it automatically added the references for me.

[image]

Go to Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.

Type Install-Package ironruby

[image]

Viola!

**EDIT**:  If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417459/downloaded-ironruby-1-1-3-but-cannot-find-ironruby-dll-or-ironruby-libraries-dl), they have a link where the bug is discussed.