# Downloaded IronRuby 1.1.3, but cannot find IronRuby.dll or IronRuby.Libraries.dll to reference

Tags: ironruby

I am trying to reference IronRuby, IronRuby.Libraries, Microsoft.Scripting, Microsoft.Scripting.Core, and Microsoft.Scripting.ExtensionAttribute in a c# program using Visual Studio 2010.

I read that you can find these .dll's under C:\Program Files\IronRuby 1.1\Lib\ironruby but there are no .dll files there. I've looked all over for these files but cannot find them. I've also searched and searched on the web for information on this and cannot find anything that helps.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jacob, you can download [a zip file which contains the binaries](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/releases/view/60511#DownloadId=217153):

Keep in mind, they are also installed by the [MSI](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/releases/view/60511#DownloadId=217152), but the assemblies are put into the GAC and are not kept in the installation directory. You can find them if you look in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

This behavior is explained in [this bug report](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/workitem/6136).

Also, you mentioned Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll and Microsoft.Scripting.ExtensionAttribute.dll. Those assemblies are not part of the .NET 4.0 installer, as those bits are included .NET 4.0's System.Core.dll. Those assemblies are only required when targeting anything earlier than .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using VS 2010, simplest way is probably to install Nuget Package Manager and add the IronRuby reference via Nuget (right click on the project, select 'Manage Nuget Packages', search for IronRuby, and hit 'Install').

Answer (score 0):

When you go to Codeplex to download the code, select the version you are looking for (1.1.3 in your case) and look under "Other Available Downloads" which has IronRuby 1.1.3 Binaries (includes binaries for Windows Phone 7).  This is just a .zip file and under the bin directory are the .dlls that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Download the [installer](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/downloads/get/217152) and run the setup.
2. Download the [binaries](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/downloads/get/217153) and *unzip* and *overwrite* on **%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IronRuby 1.1**, if you are running 64-bit WindOS OR **%ProgramFiles%\IronRuby 1.1**, if you are running 32-bit OS.
3. If you are running 64-bit OS, copy the **IronRuby 1.1** folder from **%ProgramFiles(x86)%** to **%ProgramFiles%**.
4. Launch Visual Studio and it should work fine.

Note: if you want to use igem, iirb (etc.) commands in command prompt, add a variable `IronRuby` under `System > Advanced System Settings >  User variables` with the value `%ProgramFiles%\IronRuby 1.1` OR simply append it to the *path* under System variables.